# Test-Path for everyone

Tags: powershell

I'm currently creating a script for a group of users could use it. I use `Test-Path "C:\Users\vincentw\allapps.txt` to verify if allapps.txt exists on my local system before running the script:

```
if (!(Test-Path "C:\Users\vincentw\allapps.txt")) {
    "All sw/apps" >> allapps.txt
    "-------------------------------------------------------" >> allapps.txt
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_Product |
        where {$_.Vendor -notmatch "Advanced"} | 
        Format-List name, Vendor, Version |
        Out-String).Trim() >> allapps.txt
    "-------------------------------------------------------" >> allapps.txt
} else {
    Write-Host "WARNING: File already exists!"
    break
}
```

However, the script verifying only works on my local system. I'm wondering is there any way my local username - 'vincentw' could be replaced to make the script available check every user's local path on their own systems?

Comment: Use the automatic variable `$HOME`.  This will point to `$Env:HomeDrive+$Env:HomePath` (usually, at least. I've seen mixed results on re-mapped home drives)

Comment: Alternatively use `$env:USERPROFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

If the script will be run from their user on their computer then you could use **$env:USERPROFILE**

```
Test-Path "$($env:USERPROFILE)\allapps.txt"
```

If you want to do it on all profiles you can do something like this

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\" -Directory | foreach-object{ 
    If(!(test-path "$($_.FullName)\allapps.txt")){
        "Missing : $($_.FullName)\allapps.txt"
    }Else{
        "Found : $($_.FullName)\allapps.txt"
    }
}
```

Comment: If your environment variables aren't reliable (they *can* be re-written), `$HOME` is a powershell automatic variable.